# Is light in a fridge on Shabbat "melacha shein tzricha legufo"?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, technology

I remember learning that when I open a fridge door on Shabbat and the light turns on that would be under the category of melacha shein tzricha legufo?

Can anyone please provide a source?

Comment: Are you sure it's "melacha shein tzricha legufo"; I would have thought "dovor sheaino miskavain" is more likely.

Comment: I know, i remember seeing it's melacha shein tzricha legufo. If anyone can help that would be great!

Comment: I had always heard that it’s a Psik Reisha, and it depends on external circumstances (ex. is there a bright light in the room anyway?) to determine if it’s nicha lei or lo nicha lei. It’s certainly not davar she’eino miskavein @Avrohom, and I can’t imagine a case wherein it would be eina tzricha legufa.

Comment: @Doniel Psik Reishei is a type of Eino Mitkavein.

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess technically? I tend to think of them as two separate things since halacha l’ma’aseh their halachos are very different - one is mutar lechatchilah, and the other is always assur except in certain exceptions.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11025/what-do-you-do-if-you-forgot-to-turn-off-the-refrigerator-light-before-shabbat?r=SearchResults

Comment: So it can't be in any way shape or form a melacha shein tzricha legufo

Comment: @einodmilvado You never know, someone might find something. I’m just not seeing it.

Comment: Remember that just because something is eina tzricha legufa doesn’t make it permitted, just that it’s prohibited Rabbinically. We certainly don’t offer practical halachic advice on here, so you may want to talk to your Rabbi if you’re really hoping for a heter.

Comment: @DonielF I understand, I am not looking for a practical heter, I just remember reading it and would like to see it again

Comment: If it wasn't צריכה the light wasn't there. While you're not opening the fridge to see the light, it helps a lot.

Comment: I think you confuse "learning it as a fact" and "a possibility of" and present it as a fact.

Answer (score -1):

By the way -- *melacha* is feminine, and therefore the expression is *melacha she'einah tzricha legufah" -- "work not needed for its own self." And it doesn't appear to qualify as such.

The light bulb appears instead to be a classic case of *psik reisha* -- "I just want to take the head off this chicken, I don't necessarily want the side effect of the chicken dying." Thus -- "I just want to open the door, not necessarily the side effect of the light turning on.

*Melacha she'eina tzricha legufah* means I intend to do a *melacha* action, but for a totally different purpose than its normal (or as-in-the-Mishkan) one. A normal purpose of burning is to generate light and heat; so when I flick on a light switch intending to make a tungsten filament get hot and light up the room, that is a normal use case of *hav'arah*. (An *einah tzricha legufa* case would be burning a promissory note to dispose of it after the debt's been paid. Constructive, but not the "normal" use of burning.)

Therefore pretty much anytime one turns on an incandescent bulb, it's *tzricha legufah.* The arguments instead hinge on whether my actions (opening the door) connect to the melacha (heating metal to produce light).